# How do Set Mask on Textbox Control Russian Alphabets in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am  Used Asp.net C#
I have Used Text box in Set Mask L000

```
textbox.mask=mask;
```

L For Letter

0 For For Number

Example

So My Text box is  Valid Entry is A123

Suppose I am Used Russian Language

How To Set Russian Alphabets not in English

the Regex format is

```
               { '0', @"\d" },
               { '9', @"[\d]?" },
               { 'L', "[a-zA-Z]" },
               { '?', "[a-zA-Z_ ]?" },
               { '&', @"[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}]" },
               { 'C', @"[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}]?" },
               { '#', @"[ \d+-]?" },
               { 'A', @"\W" },
               { '\\', "\\" }
```

What is Russian Regex Format?

Comment: `\p{IsCyrillic}?\d{3}` may fit to what you want. But how you want to implement it in actual code then?

Comment: i have support Russian Characters Only in My text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mask Regex is 
English Alphabets

```
{ 'L', "[a-zA-Z]" },
```

Russian Alphabets

```
{ 'L', "[А-Яа-я]" },
```

Russian Alphabets and English Alphabets:

```
{ 'L', "[А-Яа-яa-zA-Z]" },
```